# android database connection how to?

Tags: java, sql, xml

i want to connect my android program with database of the same database of my site that use sql the android program sholud register users to database and login and put info about patient in that is database

so how to is that by java or what 
my forms on mobile designed by xml

please help me

thanx

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, exposing your database directly that way is an extremely dangerous thing to you.  It would make it quite easy for someone to access your database to do something malicious.

A better approach is to program an API for your website that is essentially a version of your site that doesn't allow any access beyond what's already possible for users, but returns the results in a convenient machine-readable format like JSON or XML instead of HTML designed to be viewed in a browser.

If you're not familiar with this, you can look at other sites that provide APIs for an example of how they work and design one that makes sense for your application.